# Is There Something That can Help me Find the Minimum Number of Multiplications?

Tags: c++, optimization, mathematical-optimization, multiplication, temporary

I'm doing matrix math and I end up making horrifying arrays out of complex math, one example would be:

```
{ cosine_of_yaw * cosine_of_roll, -cosine_of_roll * sine_of_yaw * sine_of_pitch - cosine_of_pitch * sine_of_roll, sine_of_pitch * sine_of_roll - cosine_of_pitch * cosine_of_roll * sine_of_yaw,
  cosine_of_yaw * sine_of_roll, cosine_of_pitch * cosine_of_roll - sine_of_yaw * sine_of_pitch * sine_of_roll, -cosine_of_roll * sine_of_pitch - cosine_of_pitch * sine_of_yaw * sine_of_roll,
  sine_of_yaw, cosine_of_yaw * sine_of_pitch, cosine_of_yaw * cosine_of_pitch }
```

I want to find the least number of multiplications that I'd have to do, to formulate arrays. That means if I find a multiplication being repeated I need to calculate it once and use a temporary. For example I can save 1 multiplication above by making a temporary out of any one of the following:

1. `cosine_of_roll * sine_of_yaw`
2. `sine_of_pitch * sine_of_yaw`
3. `cosine_of_pitch * sine_of_yaw`
4. `sine_of_roll * sine_of_yaw`

Let's say for example that I choose **1**. This prevents me from being able to use the simplification `cosine_of_roll * cosine_of_pitch`. Is there a way that I can find the minimum subset of multiplications?

I have quite a number of these matrix multiplications so I'd love if I could just feed this to an algorithm and have it find the minimum subset. I have a sinking feeling that this is an NP-Complete problem, because the possible solution set changes each time I select a pairing. If anyone has a clever workaround I'd love to see it!

If it helps these are the variables that I'm using:

1. `sine_of_yaw`
2. `cosine_of_yaw`
3. `sine_of_pitch`
4. `cosine_of_pitch`
5. `sine_of_roll`
6. `cosine_of_roll`

Comment: Have you check the assembly before embarking on this?  A lot of times the compiler will do this for you in it's optimization pass.

Comment: Out of interest, would reducing the number of multiplications *really* make that much of a difference, cf. the evaluation of the (implied) trigonometric functions?

Comment: Enable aggressive optimizations like fast math or O3. Fast math does not try to keep order of operations on floating point. `--ffast-math` on gcc for example. Also a genetic algorithm can find it if you care to make a conversion from code ordering to DNA for it. I found a sorting network using GA once. Perhaps GA works for you too.

Comment: @NathanOliver I suspect that the compiler cannot find the optimum subset in all cases, because I suspect that the problem is NP-complete. So while I do expect that that the compiler will make a *good* choice I doubt it's ability to make the *best* choice.

Comment: @Bathsheba I don't expect a significant performance gain here no, but because of potential tightness of the loop around this code, I would find any improvement that I could get worthwhile.

Comment: @JonathanMee: I remember reading about something like this many years ago - in "Numerical Recipes in C" - where the professors are, if I recall correctly, talking about matrix multiplication. I think they pretty much say they give up and suffer the extra multiplication. Might be worth your having a read too.

Comment: @JonathanMee You should give https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm a read. It won't directly solve your problem, but it provides some interesting perspective: 1. Eliminating as many common subexpressions as possible is not a solved problem. 2. We don't even know the theoretical optimum for the (very lucrative) problem of matrix multiplication. (Although in your case you could just brute-force all possible choices I believe). 3. Theoretical performance and practical performance easily diverge (e.g. due to caches).

Comment: In short, if you are out for the absolute optimum (and not just the compiler knowing best, possibly requiring `--ffast-math`), I would just brute-force it here. Possibly even micro-benchmarking every option. That's a _ton_ of effort you are trying to invest into this bit of code though, and I'm sure that there are several other much more worthwhile optimizations (data structures/cache, vectorization, relaxing some IEEE floating point math properties...) that you might want to look into instead. Vectorization in particular adds different constraints to this problem...

Comment: Have you actually profiled this code and found out at least 1% improvement in saving __any__ multiplication result? I bet there's absolutely no improvement within the measurement error.